# Fridge Combinatorics (is it really that trivial?)

Tags: combinatorics

In my Fridge I have 2013 Meals of different types. Of each type there aren't more than 183 in quantaty.

Proof that I can eat 11 different meals each day for the next 183 days.

My solution is this:

In my Fridge I have the types a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k and maybe more.

At start I eat the meals a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k once every day. When one of the versions is gone, one of the remainding ones becomes the empty one. Therefore the other different types belong to one of the 11 types as well.

2013/11=183 --> Therefore I can eat 11 different types of meals everyday for the next 183 days.

I'm sure it can't really be this easy and I did a mistake somewhere

Comment: You have a really big fridge.

Comment: @mrf Any other hint?

Comment: Based on the title I thought something like [fridge logic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FridgeLogic) was being discussed.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\frac{2013}{11} = 183$$

Comment: That is what I wrote in my solution. However, I don't think I really proved it due to that, because I only proofed it for the special case when I have 11 types and 183 each. But not if I have 30 types and somewhere between 1 and 183 each of them

Comment: Any other hint?

Comment: Think of it in terms of multinomial coefficients perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine laying out the $2013$ meals in a rectangular array of $11$ rows and $183$ columns. Put the $n_1$ meals of type $1$ in the first $n_1$ positions in the array, reading from left to right and top to bottom. When you’ve laid out all of the type $1$ meals, continue with the type $2$ meals, then the type $3$ meals, and so on. If, for instance, $n_1=170$ and $n_2=150$, the type $1$ meals will occupy the first $170$ positions in the first row, and the type $2$ meals will occupy the last $13$ positions in the first row and the first $137$ positions in the second row. The idea is that each column should contain the meals for one day, so we’d like to show that no column can contain two meals of the same type.

Suppose that column $k$ contains two meals of type $\ell$. Then the type $\ell$ meals occupy at least the last $183-(k-1)=184-k$ positions of one row and the first $k$ positions of the next row, for a total of $184$ positions — which is impossible, since there are only at most $183$ meals of type $\ell$.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2013/183=11, you have at least 11 different types of food. If there's exactly 183 of every type, then you can eat a meal of each of these 11 types 183 times. The problem is what happens when you don't have exactly 183 of each type.

Comment: yeah, exactly that is my problem :(

Comment: What if you eat the eleven most common foods?

Comment: @Michael You can't eat them 183 times, or you'd have exactly 11 types of meal.

Comment: @RichardDuston How do you eat for 183 days if you have 183 meals of 10 types and 182 meals of one type?

Comment: @Locki Clock Well you would run out of one type at day #182 and have only 10 meals on day #183

Comment: On  the 183rd day, meal-type 11 would no longer be the most common, so you would eat meal-type 12 instead.